# jQuery via Google CDN best practices

Tags: jquery, cdn

I'm loading jQuery via Google's CDN using the following code.

My main question is what will happen if a user hits my site and hasn't yet got jQuery pre-cached. Will he download the Google version and my own? How does concurrency here work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        //<![CDATA[
        document.write("<script src='/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'><\/script>");
        //]]>
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: One question I would have is why have your second check anyway? If Google is down, I'm pretty sure most of the internet is going down with it...(I'm only half-joking). Is the redundancy really necessary?

Comment: @JasCav - There is, however small a chance, that the user can't access `google.com`, maybe in China perhaps?  Just an example off the top of my head.

Comment: @JasCav: One client once couldn't access the script on Google. I don't know the exactly reason, but it's better to prevent, a couple of lines more won't hurt.

Comment: @Nick @BrunoLM - Okay. Good points. Now that I think about it, I once ran into a similar situation. Thanks.

Comment: @JasCav I would probably go as far as to say that if Google is down no one in that area will discover my site. But as long as their are already a regular to it... no reason to let Google drag me down on the shortages (even Google!) has on some specific network points from time to time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example code they will download the google version *if* they don't already have it because of another site.  Then *if* for some reason google is down, they'll download your version, they won't download both.  The second is only requested *if* the first (from Google) fails.

The check goes like this:

1. Do we have the google version cached?

   - **Yes** - Ok good to go, use it.
   - **No** - Download it from Google, use it.
2. Is `jQuery` (the JavaScript object) defined?

   - **Yes** - ok it loaded fine, the `if()` is false, continue on.
   - **No** - *oh snap!* Google load failed, either from cache or the fetch, need to load it from elsewhere

     - Load it from your site via a new `<script>` tag just added.

Comment: perfect. Love your style of answering. Exactly what I was aiming for. Thanks.